# No options for mouse sensitivity on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mouse, 15.10

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 today on my system. This is as fresh as fresh gets: open source drivers, nothing else installed (save for GIMP now to crop a screenshot), etc. I noticed my mouse sensitivity was absurdly high inside of Ubuntu and upon going to configure my mouse in settings, I noticed the option for sensitivity/acceleration weren't there.

[Link to image showing the lack of the option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nddX9.png)

The mouse I have is a Sentey Gammitus mouse that does have a button on the mouse for configuring DPI. However, even on the lowest setting the mouse still moves too fast and combined with Ubuntu's already awful mouse acceleration, it makes the desktop very difficult to navigate.

xinput lists the following inputs

```
mike@mike-MS-7721:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ NEWMEN MOUSE                              id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard         id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CM Storm QuickFire Rapid keyboard         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Plantronics Plantronics GameCom 780/788   id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ NEWMEN MOUSE                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft LifeCam VX-800                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I am able to use the command `xinput --set-prop "12" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1.5` to set the sensitivity through Terminal but I'd still like my sensitivity to be present in the settings.

What could cause this? I have found previously reported bugs on this but it looks like they all haven't been squashed yet.